# Remove only empty "value" attribute from HTML tags

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015

I have a regular expression that I would like to use to remove empty "value" attributes in my markup. I have a RegEx, but it doesn't ignore the following attribute:

```
value="Delete Record"
```

The RegEx that I need help fixing is listed below:

```
\s+value\s*=\s*("[^"]*"|[^\s >]*|"\s*?"/)
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and your expected output?

Comment: What language? Edit your question to add appropriate tags. Then hopefully someone can point you to a DOM parser for that language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
\s+value\s*=\s*"\s*"
```

such regex allows only spaces between quotes

**[Demo and some explanation](https://regex101.com/r/M5rPd0/2)**